Is there a maximum angular acceleration due to gravity for a given radius?
I'm having trouble understanding the relationship between angular acceleration and tangential acceleration, specifically, how can an angular acceleration created by the tangential acceleration of gravity on an object with unit radius exceed $ 9.81\,\text{rad}/\text{s}^2$?
A comment on a previous edit of this question suggested I am making a false assumption about the edge of the object being unable to accelerate faster than $g$, but I don't understand why this would be the case.
If $\alpha = a_t/r$, where $r=1 \,\text{m}$ and  $a_t=9.81\,\text{m}/\text{s}^2$, then $\alpha=9.81 \,\text{rad}/\text{s}^2$.
But if I try to do the same thing using torque, it's easy to create an angular acceleration much greater than $9.81 \,\text{rad}/\text{s}^2$ by either increasing the torque or decreasing the moment of inertia.
For example, using a $1\,\text{kg}$ mass suspended from the end of a $1\,\text{m}$ beam, supported at the other end: Let's say $I=1 \,\text{kg}\,\text{m}^2$ and $\tau=(1\,\text{m})(9.81\,\text{N})(\sin{90°}) = 9.81 \,\text{N}\,\text{m}$, then $\alpha=9.81\,\text{rad}/\text{s}^2$.
But say the suspended mass is doubled, or the moment of inertia halved, suddenly we have an angular acceleration of $19.62 \,\text{rad}/\text{s}^2$.
Plugging this back into the first equation $\alpha = a_t/r$ now gives a tangential acceleration of $19.62\,\text{m}/\text{s}^2$.
Absent some kind of mechanical advantage, how can we get a tangential acceleration greater than the tangential acceleration that caused the motion? I would think that it can't exceed $g$ since $g$ is the only force acting on it.

This is an extremely poor question. Who said that the end must accelerate less than g? Don't make up rules yourself. If you use false assumptions you will derive contradictions from it. Consider the case where the mass of the beam is concentrated near the pivot. Also your moment of inertia is entirely wrong.

You need to explain and clarify why you think that the end must always accelerate less than g. Otherwise there is nothing to explain. How can this be so? Because the laws of physics say so. I think that you're failing to understand that the moment of inertia can be varied independently of the mass. Consider different mass distributions of the rod.

I think the end should not accelerate faster than g because g is the only force acting on it. I chose arbitrary values for the moment of inertia to focus attention on the end result rather than any particular mass distribution.

I dont get why doubling the mass doubles the angular acceleration

@JIMBO OK. Please edit your reasoning into your post. I will consider writing an answer if this gets reopened.

@VincentThacker Done. Thank you.

You are simply wrong when you claim that gravity is the only force acting on the end. For any rod, there are three forces on a given element:

Gravity
Internal forces applied by the element to the left
Internal forces applied by the element to the right

(Additionally, internal torques are also present.) The internal forces are what makes the rod rigid in the first place. If you hold the rod at one end and swing it, you are applying a force/torque only to the element at the end you're holding. This then applies force/torque on the next element, which then applies force/torque on the next element and so on, such that the entire rod moves together and retains its shape.

Each element is moved by the force/torque applied by the preceding element and (by Newton's third law) also resisted by the reaction from applying force/torque to the subsequent element.
These internal forces are what maintains the shape and rigidity of the rod. The only difference is that the free end will have force from one side rather than two. If gravity  were truly the only force acting on the free end, it will break off and fall downwards when the rod is held stationary, which is absurd.
So, to make it explicitly clear, the end of the rod moves together with the rest of the rod because of the elastic forces within the rod. The acceleration of the end of the rod is not limited by $g$ but rather the mechanical strength of the material.

To start with , let's take everything as a variable . Say that we have a light rod which is pivoted at one end in the vertical plane and have a point mass , $m$ attached at the other end .
Also the length of the rod is , '$r$' and acceleration due to gravity at the position is $g$ .
Now you are absolutely right in saying

I would think that it can't exceed g

in this scenario.
Let's do some calculation to understand, say we take the initial position of the rod to be horizontal ( which I think you were also assuming ).
Torque in this position about the pivot would be : $$τ=rmg \sin{90}$$$$Iα=mgr$$
Which gives :$$α=mgr/I$$$$\frac{a}{r}=\frac{mgr}{I}$$$$a=\frac{mgr²}{I}$$
Now , in this case , $I=mr²$. And hence, $$a=\frac{mgr²}{mr²}=g$$
Clearly, the tangential acceleration is not greater than $g$ in the given case , as you said which is due to the fact that gravity is the only force acting in the vertical direction ( initially ).
Now , you got the calculation wrong here:

But say the suspended mass is doubled, or the moment of inertia halved, suddenly we have an angular acceleration of 19.62radsec2
.

According to your assumption ( if mass is doubled , i.e. $m=2 kg$ ) , then,$$ τ= 2×1²×9.81$$$$α=\frac{2×9.81}{I}=\frac{2×9.81}{2×1²}=9.81 rad/s²$$$$a=αr=9.81×1 m/s²=9.81 m/s²$$
Clearly, doubling the mass or the length of rod doesn't change the acceleration (tangential).

In your example. the torque is $T = F r $ and the moment of inertia is $I = M r^2 $ and the angular acceleration is
$$\alpha  = \frac{T}{I} = \frac{F \ r}{M\ r^2} = \frac{F}{M\ r} = \frac{M\ g}{M\ r} = \frac{g}{r}.$$

But say the suspended mass is doubled, or the moment of inertia
halved, suddenly we have an angular acceleration of $19.62 \,\text{rad}/\text{s}^2$.

If the mass is doubled the result is still the same as is obvious from the equation above, because the mass variable cancels out and is not in the final result. However, the angular acceleration is dependent on $r$ and so, for example, halving $r$ would double the angular acceleration.
The tangential acceleration is given by $a_t = \alpha \ r$. If we substitute the equation obtained for $\alpha$ in this equation we get
$$a_t = \alpha r = \frac gr r = g.$$
Clearly, in your set up, the tangential acceleration is always $g$ and is independent of the mass and length of the beam.
In summary, the longer the beam, the less the angular acceleration, but the tangential velocity at the free end (where the mass is) is always $g$.
==================================
Now let's try something a little more adventurous and see if we can find an exception. Instead of the beam, we have a rod of length $\ell$, with even density distribution and with its centre of mass at the centre of the rod. The rod is suspended horizontally and supported at one end from a hinge and is free to swing down in an arc when released. The moment of inertia of such a rod is $(1/3) M \ \ell^2$. The torque acting on the rod due to the force of gravity acting on its centre is $T = Mg\ \dfrac{\ell}{2}$. Now the angular acceleration is:
$$\alpha  = \frac{T}{I} = \frac{Mg \ \ell/2}{(1/3) M\ \ell^2} = \frac{3g}{2\ell},$$
which again is independent of the mass (but not of the length).
Now, if we substitute this expression for angular acceleration into the equation for tangential acceleration we get:
$$a_t = \alpha  \ell = \frac{3g}{2\ell} \ell = \frac{3}{2} g$$
which again is independent of the mass and the length of the rod, but this time the tangential acceleration of the end of the rod is greater than $g$!
This happens because the force of gravity is acting on the centre of the rod, but we are measuring the tangential acceleration at the free end of the rod, furthest from the hinge, and the radius multiplies the acceleration. Therefore it is possible for the tangential acceleration to exceed the acceleration of gravity with the right set up. Trebuchets utilise this effect to send projectiles further.
Note, that in the case of the falling rotating rod, the tangential acceleration can be written as:
$$a_t = \alpha  r = \frac{3g}{2\ell}r ,$$
where $r$ is where the tangential acceleration is actually measured. If $r = \dfrac{\ell}{2}$ (where the centre of gravity is) the result is $a_t = 3g/4$, which is somewhat counterintuitive, because it is tempting to assume the tangential acceleration at the centre of gravity would be exactly $g$.
P.S. If you happen to be at the top of a tall telegraph pole when it starts to topple over, you should probably slide down the pole as fast as possible, because staying at the top and holding on, you could be slammed into the ground faster than if you jumped from the same height.
